# Google Data Java Client Library for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-data-api

I want to make a youtube client app for android. I was trying to follow **[this](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/picasa-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/picasa/PicasaAndroidSample.java?repo=samples)** So I need to import these:

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.InputStreamContent;
**import com.google.api.client.sample.picasa.model.AlbumEntry;

import com.google.api.client.sample.picasa.model.PicasaUrl;

import com.google.api.client.sample.picasa.model.UserFeed;

import com.google.api.client.sample.picasa.model.Util;**
import com.google.api.client.util.DateTime;
import com.google.api.client.xml.atom.AtomParser;

I am using Eclipse IDE and installed the **google-api-java-client-1.3.1-alpha.zip** as Reference Libraries.
But it is still showing error on the **Bold import statements.** How to resolve that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that you need those classes if you are creating a YouTube client. If you look at the package name, they are for Picasa, which is not YouTube.

Comment: Yes I understand that. But I was just trying to follow an example, if I can do it for Picasa I can do it for Youtube - like concept

Comment: @newcomer: Those classes are not in the JAR. You will also note that those classes have `sample` in their package name. Those classes are part of the picasa-atom-android-sample project that you linked to above.

Answer (score 0):

Hello: I think you must be looking for the following. Check the following links and you might find related classes.

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/picasa-atom-android-sample/?repo=samples

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/picasa-atom-android-sample/?repo=samples#picasa-atom-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/picasa/model

Comment: Both links are invalid now. Please update or delete your answer.